# Using hook_ds_fields_info(), is there a way to use standard formatters so the options for those formatters are available in the Manage Display UI?

Tags: drupal-7, display-suite

I followed a good tutorial here : http://previousnext.com.au/blog/creating-custom-display-suite-fields-or-how-i-learned-stop-worrying-and-use-hookdsfieldsinfo to create programmatically customs field with hook_ds_fields_info().

In my code below, I'm trying to use the text_trimmed formatter, but in the UI I don't get the settings for the trimmed format.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_ds_fields_info().
 */
function my_module_ds_fields_info($entity_type) {
  $fields = array();

  $fields['node']['article_footnote'] = array(
    'title' => t('Article footnote'),
    'field_type' => DS_FIELD_TYPE_FUNCTION,
    'function' => 'my_module_ds_field_article_footnote',
    'ui_limit' => array('my_content_type|*', '*|search_index'),
    'properties' => array(
      'formatters' => array(
        'text_default' => t('Default'),
        'text_plain' => t('Plain text'),
        'text_trimmed' => t('Trimmed'),
      ),
    ),
  );

  if (isset($fields[$entity_type])) {
    return array($entity_type => $fields[$entity_type]);
  }
  return;
}

/**
 * Render the article footnote field.
 */
function my_module_ds_field_article_footnote($field) {
  $content = 'All articles are composed in a permanent state of coffee frenzy.';
  return $content; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One piece you were missing is to filter your text through [check_markup()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21filter%21filter.module/function/check_markup/7) in your callback function. Without that, you are just returning a regular string.

Also, it's a good idea to use the default list of text formats that are configured in the system by calling [filter_formats()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21filter%21filter.module/function/filter_formats/7).

Here's the revised code which should work. Once you have that code in place, try switching the format of the field and then view your node to see the different results. I added some HTML to your string so you can see the differences.

```
<?php
/**
 * Implements hook_ds_fields_info().
 */
function my_module_ds_fields_info($entity_type) {
  $fields = array();

  // Build a list of input formats.
  $formatters = array();
  $filter_formats = filter_formats();
  foreach ($filter_formats as $format) {
    $formatters[$format->format] = $format->name;
  }

  $fields['node']['article_footnote'] = array(
    'title' => t('Article footnote'),
    'field_type' => DS_FIELD_TYPE_FUNCTION,
    'function' => 'my_module_ds_field_article_footnote',
    'ui_limit' => array('my_content_type|*', '*|search_index'),
    'properties' => array(
      'formatters' => $formatters,
    ),
  );

  if (isset($fields[$entity_type])) {
    return array($entity_type => $fields[$entity_type]);
  }
  return;
}

/**
 * Render the article footnote field.
 */
function my_module_ds_field_article_footnote($field) {
  $content = check_markup('<h1>All articles</h1> are composed in a permanent state of <strong>coffee frenzy</strong>.', $field['formatter']);
  return $content; 
}
?>
```